# Sort php array based on current time

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am currently using the following json data. (The key is a time hh:mm)

```
 "chart": {
    "23:20": 11,
    "23:30": 11,
    "23:40": 11,
    "23:50": 16,
    "00:00": 16,
    "00:10": 14,
    "00:20": 11,
    "00:30": 12,
    "00:40": 14,
    "00:50": 10,
    "01:00": 8,
    "01:10": 12,
    "01:20": 15,
    "01:30": 13,
    "01:40": 11,
    "01:50": 8,
    "02:00": 8
 }
```

https://pastebin.com/cp16Rr9w

I am then moving the data to a php array. I would like to sort the array, so it starts at the current server time and goes on from there.

At the moment i am using the following php (unsorted)

```
  <?php
    foreach ($data['chart'] as $key => $value){
        echo 'Time: '.$key.'Data: '.$value;
    }
  ?>
```

Comment: there are now tons of answers on SO about sorting arrays, tell us what have you tried and if there are issue with your tries.

Comment: I have been looking into uksort but i never tried it since i didn't understand it

Comment: can you add an example of the output you would like to have?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach perhaps would be to filter out all "too old" entries first with `array_filter()` and then sort the resulting array using `ksort()`:

```
<?php

function getFilter($server_time) {
    return function($item) use($server_time) {
       return (strtotime($item) >= $server_time);
    };
}

$data = '{"chart": {
          "23:20": 11,"23:30": 11,"23:40": 11,"23:50": 16,"00:00": 16,
          "00:10": 14,"00:20": 11,"00:30": 12,"00:40": 14,"00:50": 10,
          "01:00": 8,"01:10": 12,"01:20": 15,"01:30": 13,"01:40": 11,
          "01:50": 8,"02:00": 8
}}';

$json = json_decode($data, true);
$src = $json['chart'];

$server_time = strtotime("now");

$filtered = array_filter($src, getFilter($server_time), ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
ksort($filtered);

print_r($filtered);
```

Live test case: https://3v4l.org/M3RLm

Comment: I do not understand uksort().. So i have this `$time = date("H:i");
  function timeSort($a, $b){
  if ($a == $b) return 0;
  return ($a < $b)?-1:1;
  }
  
  uksort($data['chart'],"timeSort");` I don't understand where to use the `$time` variable

Comment: Put `var_dump($a);` in your `timeSort()` method body and you will see... Trial and error!

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I think it is not about sorting only, "so it starts at the current server time and goes on from there."

Comment: Actually I completely reworked the answer. "Sorting first" approach is a waste in such case.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
$data = json_decode('{"chart": {
    "23:20": 11,
    "23:30": 11,
    "23:40": 11,
    "23:50": 16,
    "00:00": 16,
    "00:10": 14,
    "00:20": 11,
    "00:30": 12,
    "00:40": 14,
    "00:50": 10,
    "01:00": 8,
    "01:10": 12,
    "01:20": 15,
    "01:30": 13,
    "01:40": 11,
    "01:50": 8,
    "02:00": 8
}}');

$data = (array) $data->chart;

function sort_time($a, $b) { return strtotime($a) > strtotime($b); }

uksort($data, 'sort_time' );

foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key: $value\n";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function hsort($a, $b) // callback function for uksort function
{
    return (floatval(str_replace(":", ".", $a)) - floatval(str_replace(":", ".", $b))) // convert each time to float value, like '01:56'-> "01.56", then compare values as float
}

$chart = array_flip($chart); // flip indexes with values to get ability to operate with indexes as array values (which are time in your array)
uksort($chart, "hsort"); // sort time values
$chart = array_flip($chart); // flip again to make time values as index again
```

Comment: This explains nothing. Can i have an explanation?

Comment: added comments.

Comment: So as far as i can see, this just sorts the time from lowest to highest?

Comment: actually, it flips it so its just sorting the values highest to lowest?

Comment: yes it sorts time, but keeps value for each time too

Comment: What i was asking is that i want the array to start at the current time `date(H:i);`

Comment: you use time values as a index in array, but we can sort array values only, so that's the way why i flip indexes with values. after sorting i flip it again, to make time array index

Comment: please edit your question then. you don't need sort array, you need to slice part of array, starting from current server time